# Resolving parent/child with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, circular-dependency

I am not sure calling this parent/child but here you go, I have a similar case like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
    using Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.SpecializedResolvers;
    using Castle.Windsor;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));

            container.Register(
                Component.For<Parent>().LifeStyle.Singleton,
                Component.For<IChild>().ImplementedBy<Child1>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

            var p = container.Resolve<Parent>();

            // Fails...
            Debug.Assert(p.Children.First().Parent == p, "Parent should be resolved");
        }
    }

    class Parent
    {
        public IChild[] Children { get; set; }
    }

    interface IChild
    {
        Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    class Child1 : IChild
    {
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have CollectionResolver added to the container. Both Parent and Child1 (with IChild service) are registered as singletons in the container. Whenever I try to resolve the Parent instance, I got my Children array populated but the Child1 instance in that array has a Parent of null. What I am expecting is the Parent property of the Child1 to be set to the Parent instance I am trying to resolve at that moment. I can understand that Parent is not fully activated yet, but since its ctor is run, can't Windsor inject this property yet? Are there any way to make this work or should I manually run some code to set Parents of child objects (which is far from ideal)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor won't let you create a cyclic dependency chain. If you change your child and parent definitions so that they use constructor injection rather than property injection as follows:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(IChild[] children)
    {
        Children = children;
    }

    public IChild[] Children { get; private set; }
}

interface IChild
{
    Parent Parent { get; }
}

class Child1 : IChild
{
    public Child1(Parent parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

When you run your test now, you'll see that Windsor complains about a dependency cycle:

> Test 'M:Mike.DIDemo.WindsorSpike.ParentChild' failed: A cycle was
>   detected when trying to resolve a dependency. The dependency graph
>   that resulted in a cycle is:
>    - Parameter dependency 'children' type 'Mike.DIDemo.IChild[]' for Void .ctor(Mike.DIDemo.IChild[]) in type Mike.DIDemo.Parent
>    - Service dependency 'parent' type 'Mike.DIDemo.Parent' for Void .ctor(Mike.DIDemo.Parent) in type Mike.DIDemo.Child1  + Parameter
>   dependency 'children' type 'Mike.DIDemo.IChild[]' for Void
>   .ctor(Mike.DIDemo.IChild[]) in Mike.DIDemo.Parent

It's always better to use constructor injection when you have a required dependency. Using property injection tells Windsor that the dependency is optional: Supply the component if you can, otherwise just leave the property null. In this case the children were resolved first, so when it came to create the Parent dependency Windsor saw that a cycle would result and left it null.

The solution here is to populate the Parent when the children are resolved, by putting some code in the Parent constructor.

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(IChild[] children)
    {
        Children = children;
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public IChild[] Children { get; private set; }
}

interface IChild
{
    Parent Parent { get; set;  }
}

class Child1 : IChild
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. I will go this route, albeit it smells.

Comment: I do wonder if Windsor is the right tool for the job you have at hand. It looks like you are creating a domain object graph. It's generally not a good idea to get Windsor to create domain instances, it's more common to have some repository supply them. You would then ask Windsor for the repository rather than the domain instances.

Comment: Actually the Parent here represents a ViewModel of a WPF screen, and the Child represents an Action that can be invoked on that screen, which are visualized as Button controls. My ViewModel should know the available actions to present them, and each action should know the ViewModel they are on to interact with it. This seems to be an OK case to use a dependency container since I have some built-in actions and also custom actions provided through extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to create an object without invoking its constructor. All of its fields will be null, but you'll have a reference to object. This feature is not implemented in Windsor, and something that requires this is likely to be a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation that's a bit nicer :)

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<SearchCommand>());
container.Register(Component.For<ShowOptionsCommand>());
container.Register(Component.For<MainWindowViewModel>().OnCreate(new Action<MainWindowViewModel>(p => p.SetUpCommands())));

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ShowOptionsCommand ShowOptions { get; set; }
    public SearchCommand Search { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void SetUpCommands()
    {
        this.ShowOptions.Host = this;
        this.Search.Host = this;
    }
}
```